# How can I have console output display to stdout AND store it in a variable?

Tags: ruby, console, rake, stdout

If I do this:

```
output = %x{some_script}
```

...then I have the stuff printed to stdout stored in `output`; but I *don't* see it appear on the screen.

On the other hand, if I do this:

```
success = system "some_script"
```

...then I see the output appear on the screen, but I don't have it stored in a variable (`success` just holds a boolean value).

Is there some way to get both? I'm aware I could do this:

```
output = %x{some_script}
puts output
```

But the problem there is that `some_script` might be a pretty long-running script, in which case I see *nothing* until the whole thing is finished. I'd prefer to see output as it's produced, and when it's finished to have it all stored in the `output` variable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a solution with `IO.popen`:

```rb
require 'stringio'

output = StringIO.new

IO.popen("ls") do |pipe|
  pipe.each do |line|
    output.puts line
    puts line
  end
end

puts output.string # => Outputs the contents of `output` as a string
```

Comment: Or use [`popen3`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open3/rdoc/classes/Open3.html#M001644) if the standard error stream is also desired.

Comment: Am I missing something? This also appears to wait until the command has finished executing, much like the `%x{}` + `puts` option.

Comment: @Dan: Sounds like you have a buffering problem.

Comment: My mistake: I used an overly simplistic script to test this on; after taking the hint from @mu and actually trying it on my real script, I see that it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could monkeypatch `Kernel::puts`, but I can only think of a kludgy global way to store the results:

```
class Kernel
  alias_method :old_puts, :puts
  def puts(*args)
    old_puts args
    $output << args
  end
end
```